# get number of written rows after tableInsert via DolphinDB Java API

Tags: dolphindb

I used the method but it failed to print the number of written rows.

```
Entity entity = conn.run("tableInsert(...)")
System.out.println(entity.rows())
```

Answer (score 0):

When using DolphinDB Java API, the entity returned by `tableInsert` is of BasicInt type. Print entity and you can get the number of written rows.